# Redirect to another action in submit function in a multiple button form

Tags: 8, forms

I wanted to alter a form to add a new button. I implemented the hook_form_alter() and this works fine.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){

  $confirm = [
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Action to do'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'mymodule_secondAction',
        'event' => 'click',
      ),
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['button--primary']]
    ];
  }
  $form['confirm']=$confirm;
}
```

In the function mymodule_secondAction,in somes conditions,  I would like to call an action that already exists in the original form (for exemple ::firstAction).

```
function mymodule_secondAction(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
  $selected_data = $form_state->getValue('data');
  if ($selected_data === 'toto'){
    //do something
  } 
  else if ($selected_data === 'tutu'){
    //submit the firstAction , I tried this :
    $form_state->setSubmitHandlers(['::firstAction']);
    $form_id ='\Drupal\other_module\Form\OriginalForm';
    return \Drupal::formBuilder()->submitForm($form_id, $form_state);
  }
}
```

Submit the form with `\Drupal::formBuilder()->submitForm($form_id, $form_state);` seems not to work.
How can I do that ?
Thanks for your responses.

Comment: First of all, an ajax callback is not a form action, it is a delivery method. Then it's unclear if this is about code sharing (which you can by refactoring the code) or you want to submit a second form object (which is not possible because the first form action is already submitted at this point and you can't share the submitted data with a second form).

Comment: Indeed ajax callback is not a form action, sorry for this shortcut. Thanks for your reponse, I think I will look for another solution.